# bootstrap.css not work in angular2 universal

Tags: angular, universal

i m using angular2 universal ,
add  bootstrap.min.css in index.html head,but could not work, display 404 err, only ues the method in @Component styleUrls:['bootstrap.css'] could work . why and how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: of course  ,i add it in index.html, and i did not write styleUrls:['bootstrap.css'] in @component,but could not work ,  so i only can use the method that  write in styleUrls. but i wont  use the second method, pls think about angular2 universal environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css   and copy css file in src/assets file could solve  this problem ,because in server.ts file  app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'), {maxAge: 30}))

Answer (score 2):

If you add it in **index.html**, you don't need to write `styleUrls:['bootstrap.css']` line. Just remove it and it should work.

`styleUrls:['somefile.css']` You can use this when there is a file named **somefile.css** resides within root of you directory. So `styleUrls:['somefile.css']` syntax will fetch that file to your component.

Comment: plus 1 for that @micronyks

Comment: On a funny note, you haven't given me +1 yet. +1 can be given by up-voting the answer @Vikrant

Comment: of course  ,i add it in index.html, and i did not write styleUrls:['bootstrap.css'] in @component,but could not work ,  so i only can use the method that  write in styleUrls. but i wont  use the second method